# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean while accessing from out side

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have created a Web Service client project with spring 3, Maven, JAXB using maven plugin. It is working and giving me result while testing it with main method. But I want to use this a third party JAR in my another project. 
My Pom is like

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
    <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <cglib.version>2.2</cglib.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- CGLib for @Configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>springsource-milestones</id>
        <name>SpringSource Milestones Proxy</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource-milestones</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <generatePackage>com.yagnaiq.client.wsdl</generatePackage>
                <generateDirectory>src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                <!-- <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate> -->
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <url>http://localhst/WS/endpoints/copyProjectService.wsdl</url>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin> -->
        <!-- <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.client.test.RunCopyProjectClient</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin> -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>WSClientAll</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My Config class look like

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("com.client.wsdl");
    return marshaller;
}

@Bean
public CopyProjectClient copyProjectClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
    CopyProjectClient copyProjectClient = new CopyProjectClient();
    copyProjectClient.setDefaultUri("http://localhost/WS/endpoints/copyProjectService.wsdl");
    copyProjectClient.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    copyProjectClient.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    return copyProjectClient;
}
```

When I generated my jar file with all dependency and added it to another project as dependency , no error while compilation, getting following error while running

"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientConfiguration': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [javax.enterprise.deploy.spi.status.ClientConfiguration]: Specified class is an interface"

Calling code is like:

```
public MasterClient serviceCall() {
    MasterClient masterClient = null;
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(ClientConfiguration.class);
    ctx.refresh();// error here
    if (webservice.equals("COPY_PROJECT")) {
        CopyProjectClient copyProjectClient = ctx
                .getBean(CopyProjectClient.class);
        copyProjectClient.setDefaultUri(wsdllocation);
        masterClient = (MasterClient) copyProjectClient;
    }
}
```

Comment: May you please post the code for ClientConfiguration class

Comment: Yes post the code of `ClientConfiguration` class because with the message error it's considered like an interface